# Frontend for Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: reactjs, hyperledger-composer

I am making a blockchain application with hyperledger composer. Can i write the frontend for hyperledger composer application in react or it can only be written in angular ?

Answer (score 4):

You can write frontend code for hyperledger composer application in **any language** that you want, as it is generating **REST API**.

So, you just have to access the REST API in your frontend application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the react frsamework - in fact there is a composer sample on github that uses react!

It is the [Letter of Credit](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-applications/tree/master/packages/letters-of-credit) sample application.